# Wordpress button with dynamic url

Tags: php, wordpress, url, woocommerce

I have added a custom button to my woocomerce product pages using the following code.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_extra_button_on_product_page', 30 );

function my_extra_button_on_product_page() {
  global $product;
  echo '<a href="URL">Extra Button</a>';
}
```

I would like to build the buttons url dynamically using the

```
get_option('myplugin_option_name')
```

I'm hoping this will be possible.

'myplugin_option_name' is a custom set value via a simple plugin that adds the field to the admin options. The plugin works and I can display whatever is set in the backend on the front end using a simple :

```
<?php echo get_option('myplugin_option_name'); ?>
```

The question is how do I get the value from myplugin_option_name to be added to the button url?

So for example if 'myplugin_option_name' = buy the button url should be generated as such :

http://sample.com/buy/product_id

Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_extra_button_on_product_page', 30 );

function my_extra_button_on_product_page() {
  global $product;

  $url_part = get_option('myplugin_option_name');
  $id = $product->get_id();
  $url = home_url("/".$url_part."/".$id);
  echo '<a href="'.$url.'">Extra Button</a>';
}
```

Comment: You can add class="button btn" if you need to look it like button

Comment: @mujeebu that worked flawlessly. thank you very much. 

If I may bother you with one more thing - 
Would I be able to add another url part to include the product ID of the item via : wc_get_product()->get_id(); as well? 

so the url would essentially read 

example.com/myplugin_option_name/product-id

many thanks for your help!